# The on `data` or `error` is never fired on createKeyStream level

Tags: leveldb

I have the following code to return all the keys in the level DB in Node.js app, this is a method in a ES6 class:

```
   class LevelDB {

        constructor() {
            this.db = level(chainDB);
        }

        getAllItems() {
            let self = this;
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
               self.db.createKeyStream()
                 .on('data', function (data) {
                    resolve(data);
                 })
                 .on('error', function (err) {
                    reject(err)
              });
          }
   }
```

The database is created successfully.
What I'm notice is that the `on data` or `on error` is never fired? Im new using level so any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solve the issue;
I just realize that I need to wait for the Stream close:

```
class LevelDB {

        constructor() {
            this.db = level(chainDB);
        }

        getAllItems() {
            let self = this;
            let dataArray = [];
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
             self.db.createKeyStream()
               .on('data', function (data) {
                  dataArray.push(data);
                })
               .on('error', function (err) {
                  reject(err)
                })
               .on('close', function () {
                  resolve(dataArray);
                })
           }
       }
```